# How to prioritize the kafka topic and listen the topic with high priority over the low priority one using spring boot and java

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to listen with `@KafakListener` and publishing the message using `kafkatemplate`.

I did try using the Concurrency but it is not working as expected.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic-p", concurrency ="1")
@KafkaListener(topics= "topic-np", concurrency="1") 
public void listen(@Payload MyRequest myRequest, @Headers HeadersAccessor headers){
}
```

Not sure how to actually implement this from end to end. Can anyone suggest me how I can find a resolution for this.

Went through some documentation too but didn't find any perfect solution

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What kind of concurrency you are referring to?

Comment: If you are publishing the same data u you are listening to, I believe that doesn't really need any brainer - since it is just listen and put in another topic using KafkaTemplate.

Comment: However, you plan to listen to multiple topics, and then decide which one to process (i.e. send further), you will need intermediate storage like database or cache.

Comment: Try to find some solution for you from this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655361/does-kafka-support-priority-for-topic-or-message

Comment: I am using below code :
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic-p", concurrency ="1")
@KafkaListener(topics= "topic-np", concurrency="1")
public void listen(@Payload MyRequest myRequest, @Headers HeadersAccessor headers)